# How to reference a slug from a different model in get_success_url?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

### Setup

I have two models in my app. One is for a Journal and the other one is for entries to that journal. I wrote a CreateView class that will allow user to create a Journal entry for any Journal id currently located in. Ideally I want the class to "refresh" with the updated entry or in other words the get_success_url should lead the page we are currently located at.

**views.py**

```py
class ToJournalEntriesList(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = to_journal_entry
    template_name = 'to_journals/to_journal_entries_list.html'
    fields = ('body',)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('to-journals', kwargs={'slug':self.object.slug})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        current_journal = to_journal.objects.get(journal_user=self.request.user, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.journal_user = self.request.user
        form.instance.journal_name = current_journal
        return super(ToJournalEntriesList, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ToJournalEntriesList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['to_journal_entries'] = to_journal_entry.objects.all()
        return context
```

**models.py**

```py
class to_journal(models.Model):
    journal_name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='journal_name')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    journal_user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.journal_user) + " " + self.journal_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('to-journals')


class to_journal_entry(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    journal_name = models.ForeignKey(to_journal, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    journal_user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.journal_name) + " " + str(self.entry_date)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('to-journal-entries', args=(self.slug))
```

**urls.py**

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', CreateToJournal.as_view(), name='to-journals'),
    path('<slug:slug>', ToJournalEntriesList.as_view(), name='to-journal-entries'),
]
```

### Error

With the current setup that I have I get:

[image]

Which makes sense, because the to_journal_entry model does not have that that field.

### Question

I am sure both my `get_success_url()` in **views.py** and `get_absolute_url()` in **models.py** are done incorrectly, but I could not find a good explanation of how those work. How should I set them up to achieve desired result? Thanks a ton in advance!

I appreciate everyone taking a look. Best, Rasul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just follow the relationship:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('to-journals', kwargs={'slug': self.object.journal_name.slug})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `self.object` is a `to_journal_entry`. You probably want to use the `to_journal`, you can do that by obtaining the `journal_name`:

```
class ToJournalEntriesList(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = to_journal_entry
    template_name = 'to_journals/to_journal_entries_list.html'
    fields = ('body',)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('to-journals', kwargs={ 'slug': self.object.journal_name.slug })
```

> **Note**: usually the names of the models are written in PerlCase, so `JournalEntry` instead of <s>`to_journal_entry`</s>.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem
Thanks. I am planning to change the model name, but am scared to do that, because a lot of the things my break. Additionally I worry that there might be an issue with the database (since they are already named with this silly naming convention I have). Do you have any advice or resource that would be helpful for someone who wants to rename the model? Thanks.